# What is the difference between Lisp macros and scala macros?

Tags: scala, macros, lisp, scala-macros

Is there any fundamental difference between Lisp macros and scala macros?

I understand that macros are means to program the programs, so to say. They extend the language. But are they equally powerful? Are there some restrictions to scala macros in comparison to Lisp macros? Is it appropriate to say that lisp macros are more powerful? Do scala macros have some limits of applicability compared to Lisp macros?

If there is no conceptual difference between Lisp and scala macros, then one can just study mechanics of Lisp macros and then just apply to scala. But if scala macros are not as powerful as Lisp macros then it is impossible. There is a lot of good literature on Lisp but not so much on scala.

Comment: Is the question, does all literature about lisp macros apply equally to scala?

Comment: it is also partly about literature as consequence

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/macros-in-scala-3/6961

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-Lisp-macros-more-powerful-than-Scala-macros-Why-or-why-not https://www.quora.com/Are-there-things-that-Clojure-macros-can-do-but-Scala-macros-cant

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Racket-macros-Template-Haskell-Camlp4-and-Scala-macros-Theyre-all-for-compile-time-meta-programming-but-what-are-the-detailed-differences-in-their-expressiveness-and-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lisp is dynamically typed language. Scala is statically typed language and its type system is pretty powerful.

Macros in Scala can transform AST depending on its type (or types of its subtrees) and can even change its type. So macros in Scala are not only syntactic but also semantic.

Also look at remarks about macros in Scala vs. macros in Lisp in thesis https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf#chapter.10 , p. 206.

Comment: Scala macros must type check after expansion, but it's also true that compiler internals are "fragile" enough (that is, under-specified enough) that the expansion is equally fragile. In the answer, a macro "can even change its type" means more modestly that a "white box" macro can narrow its result type.

Comment: but in lisp one can theoretically create system of macros which will mimic types, while in scala one cannot get rid of types. Does it mean that lisp macros are more powerful? In other words, are there some problems one cannot solve with scala macros or could solve with tremendous difficulties? from swiss dissertation I understood that scala does have some restrictions which lisp doesn't have. because of macros it is often said that lisp has no syntax, but one cannot say the same about scala, right?

Comment: @G.S. Not really. In the same sense C++ is not more powerful than brainf*ck sicne their both turing complete you can build anything so you can circumvent Scala types by making an "any" type such that the type becomes dynamic because all values would be considered the same type.

Comment: by powerful I mean ability for high-level abstraction and following comfort for the programmer, of course not in the sense of creating Turing machine. by powerful I mean solving problems easily compared to another language. of course one could write a lisp compiler in c++ and then say c++ is powerful, I do not mean that. I mean ease with which high-level abstractions can be created

Comment: If language A is more restrictive than language B, does this mean that A is less powerful than B? If so then all dynamically typed languages are more powerful than statically typed ones because latter are more restrictive than former. ;)

Comment: Lisp macros don't operate on an AST, so they are not bound to transforming and creating parseable code.

Comment: @RainerJoswig a few "for instance,"s to go with that comment would be immensely more helpful.

Comment: @WillNess: true, but unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to contrast it to Scala macros. I have to hope somebody with more knowledge with Macros in Scala AND Lisp both can expand and compare that.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I meant, to expand on the Lisp side only. "they are not bound to ..." for instance, they can do ... what? And if not on AST, then on what? that's what I meant.

Comment: @WillNess: that part is probably already answered several times on Stackoverflow. As the original poster said, there is a lot of documentation/literature about Lisp macros. The answer of Dmytro points to a great paper about a range of Scala macro research, but I have no idea how much of that  is actually used in Scala - so what the real limitations are. Will, don't hesitate though to add some examples of Lisp macros, bending syntax. ;-) CL:LOOP is a simple standard example.

Comment: @RainerJoswig ah, now it's a bit clearer! so, you meant processing / creating a completely new non-Lisp-like language. (of course if such language's code is *created*, it must be processed further by some macro that will eventually turn it into a regular CL syntax, right? a macroexpansion is eventually evaluated, correct?) OK, thanks. See, examples help!

Comment: @WillNess: sorry, I did not think that was unclear. A macro could take infix syntax and create a new macro form which uses postfix syntax. That macro could then create prefix from it. If your language uses a parser+AST, then new syntax for example might not be possible, because the macro form can't be parsed into an AST. If you read the paper, they mention for example that for some Scala macro, the source needs to be compatible with the normal and fixed language syntax. They also cited this as an advantage, since the user will not have to understand new syntax for macros applications.